# Can't run cocos2dx win32 sample application in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Following this [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Cocos2d-x_Application_Wizard_for_Visual_Studio_User_Guide), I have success running build-win32.bat and also building the visual studio 2010 solution for cocos2dx. But I can't run HelloCPP.exe, HelloLua.exe, testcpp.exe, etc.

I am using the latest of cocos2dx (cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2), running windows 7 64bit and have been installing PowerVR Insider SDK.

When I tried to run HelloCpp and HelloLua from Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate version), the debugger is break at CCGLProgram.cpp:

```
bool CCGLProgram::initWithVertexShaderByteArray(const GLchar* vShaderByteArray, const GLchar* fShaderByteArray)
{
    m_uProgram = glCreateProgram();
```

The error message was: (shown in the debug console of VS 2010)

```
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\HelloCpp.exe', Symbols loaded.
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\libcocos2d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\libxml2.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\zlib1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\libtiff.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\pthreadVCE2.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'D:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2\Release.win32\iconv.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5\msvcr90.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloCpp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Not totally ready :( 

OpenGL 2.0 not supported

First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in HelloCpp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in HelloCpp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is PowerVR Insider SDK .
If you have loaded the entire cocos2d solution in msvc you cannot run it, instead right click on a project and debug->startnewinstance ,the project runs . the exe is located at Release.win32 or debug.win32 if you want to open individually.

Comment: That's what I did, and the debugger stop attthe line code I wrote above